# SCSS behavior with negative margin

Tags: sass

Let's take this SCSS code :

```css
$margin: 10px;
.use_value {
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
.use_var {
  margin: $margin 0 0 $margin;
}
.use_negative_var {
  margin: -$margin 0 0 -$margin;
}
```

I expected `.use_value`, `.use_var` and `.use_negative_var` to be identic, but here's the result :

```css
.use_value {
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
.use_var {
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
.use_negative_var {
  margin: 10px 0 -10px; 
}
```

Why is there a missing `0` in `.use_negative_var` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to interpolate the variable:

```css
$margin: 10px;

.use_value {
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.use_var {
  margin: $margin 0 0 $margin;
}

.use_negative_var {
  margin: -#{$margin} 0 0 -#{$margin};
}
```

Comment: Without interpolation, is it interpreted like `[-margin, 0, 0-margin]` ?

Comment: @zessx - why don't you check the compiled file?

Comment: Obviously, you've got the solution, I'm just thinking about the *Why*.

Comment: @zessx - sass doesn't support the syntax you tried, so I don't know what the actual result would be. Whenever your variables are not surrounded by whitespace, you have to interpolate them.

Comment: Ok, glad to learn it, thanks !